# Can a 32-bit antivirus program protect you from 64-bit threats

Tags: 64-bit, process, anti-virus, 32-vs-64-bit

I *think* that 32-bit programs cannot look inside 64-bit processes. So I am asking this question out of curiosity.

I am using Windows 7 x64. I do not know about the bitness of the antivirus except that it is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: All real-time AV scanners employ kernel drivers to hook into filesystem activity. On 64-bit systems this of course needs a 64-bit kernel driver.

Comment: @DanielB does it mean that 32-bit antivirus won't work on Windows x64?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you think a “32-bit AV scanner” is. If you’re referring to one that doesn’t ship 64-bit components at all, then yes, real-time monitoring is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how the antivirus software works.

32-bit programs might not be able to interoperate directly with *running* 64-bit processes (other than through the Windows API), but they do still have access to the entire file system including files containing 64-bit code. So technically *yes* a purely 32-bit antivirus could still do it's job and identify viruses in 64-bit files via traditional file-scanning techniques.

**However...**

The fact that an application is installed into `C:\Program Files (x86)` doesn't actually mean it's 32-bit.

- You can have 64-bit applications running from `C:\Program Files (x86)`
- You can have 32-bit applications running from `C:\Program Files`.
- Many applications actually contain a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit files but install to only *either* `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files`. A good example is VMware Workstation. On my 64-bit system, it installs to `C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation`. The files installed to that location are a mix of 32-bit *and* 64-bit EXE/DLL files, among other random files.

So what's the name and version of the antivirus software you're running? Chances are good that it *does* have 64-bit components in there and that they are being used on your 64-bit system.

You can easily check what bitness your background antivirus processes are running as by launching *Resource Monitor*. You just need to make sure the *Platform* column is showing (right click on any column then click on *Select Columns...*:

[image: Resource Monitor]

Look for your antivirus processes in the list see what bitness they're running as. You might find that the antivirus GUI runs as a 32-bit process, yet the engine itself runs as a 64-bit process. That's pretty common.

Let us know what you discover ;-)

Comment: Yes, just noticed that the antivirus' GUI module has a `*32` next to it but the shield module does not.

Comment: @SalmanA Ah yes, you're seeing that in Task Manager? Seems like all is well then. On a 64-bit system, processes listed in Task Manager are all 64-bit *except* those with the *32 suffix (which, as you observed yourself, are the 32-bit ones).